# generate rss feed for an action with a parameter

Tags: cakephp, rss

I need to generate an RSS feed for a function productList which creates a paginated list of products based on the category. the prototype of the function is

```
public function productList($category){}
```

This function resides in the Products controller. I have seen tutorials on how to generate the RSS feed.
IN the tutorials, the prototype of the function is

```
public function index(){}
```

The function does not have an argument. In the tutorial, the link to generate the RSS feed is `app_name/Products/index.rss`. This type of link is not possible in my case, because the function productList has a parameter. I want to generate an RSS based on the category selected (the  15 most recent products in that category). How do I generate an RSS for a function with a parameter in Cakephp.
One way is to set the parameter in session and not pass an argument.i.e. put $category in session so that the function prototype becomes

```
public function productList()
```

Then I would have to use a different function to generate the RSS feed and another to generate the output. 
Is there a way I can use the same function productList to generate the RSS feed without using sessions.
Please guide me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The right way in Cake2.x would be to use query strings to pass params. See [RSS in CakePHP](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/10/03/rss-feeds-in-cakephp/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two options I know about:

1] use named params in the url e.g. `example.com/controller/productList/category:2/.rss`
the category is then accessible in your productList action as `$this->params['named']['category'] == 2`

---

2] do it via routing, e.g. define a route in `routes.php` like

```
Router::connect('/engines', array('controller'=>'c', 'action'=>'productList', 'engines');
Router::connect('/gears',   array('controller'=>'c', 'action'=>'productList', 'gears');
```

that together with `parseExtension` will call productList('engines') in case of example.com/engines.rss url

Comment: thanks for the answer. the thing that worked for me was the named parameter. I have the rss feed, but I have a warning like Entity 'nbsp' not defined in Entity, line: 2 . I have a hundred of these warnings until the working memory is exhausted. Whats wrong? please help me